# INNER JOIN YII2 in ModelSearch

Tags: sql, yii2, inner-join

I would like to implement this query in my model Search :

```
    SELECT 
         van.[ID_VANTIVE]
        ,van.[ID_VANTIVE_ANTIGO]
        ,van.[STATUS]
        ,van.[NUM_LP]
        ,van.[CLIENTE]
        ,van.[ENDERECO_TIPO]
        ,van.[ENDERECO]
        ,van.[ENDERECO_NUM]
        ,van.[ENDERECO_COMPLEMENTO]
        ,van.[CEP]
        ,van.[ENDERECO_MUNICIPIO]
        ,van.[ESTADO]
        ,van.[ESTADO_COD]
        ,van.[PRODUTO]
        ,van.[VELOCIDADE_ACESSO]
        ,van.[CodCliente]
        ,van.[tipo_saida_atend]
        ,van.[CAR_COD_GRUPO]
        ,van.[CAR_GRUPO]
        ,van.[CAR_RAZAO_SOCIAL]
        ,van.[CAR_SEGMENTO_CATEGORIA]
        ,van.[CAR_SEGMENTO_VALOR]
        ,van.[CAR_SERVICE_MANAGER]
        ,van.[CAR_LIDER_POS_VENDAS]
        ,van.[CAR_COORDENADOR_POS_VENDAS]
        ,van.[CAR_GERENTE_POS_VENDAS]
        ,van.[TIPO_SMART]
        ,n.[NodeID]
        ,n.[IP_Address]
        ,n.[Country]
        ,n.[Nome_do_cliente]
        ,n.[Nome_do_device]
        ,n.[Nome_do_site]
        ,n.[Operação]
        ,n.[Operadora]
        ,n.[Pacote_Smart]
    FROM [VANTIVE].[dbo].[TABELACO] AS van
    INNER JOIN [SOLARWINDS].[dbo].[TB_NODES_SMART] AS n
    ON van.[ID_VANTIVE] = n.[NodeID]
```

My Search :

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = TABELACO::find();
```

Emphasizing that the query, besides being between two tables, are with two databases.

I tried in several ways, but with no success, please somebody help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be like

NOTE :EDIT UR DB NAMES WHEN UR EXECUTE

```
USE 
**[THE DATABASE NAME1]**
GO

 SELECT 
         van.[ID_VANTIVE]
        ,van.[ID_VANTIVE_ANTIGO]
        ,van.[STATUS]
        ,van.[NUM_LP]
        ,van.[CLIENTE]
        ,van.[ENDERECO_TIPO]
        ,van.[ENDERECO]
        ,van.[ENDERECO_NUM]
        ,van.[ENDERECO_COMPLEMENTO]
        ,van.[CEP]
        ,van.[ENDERECO_MUNICIPIO]
        ,van.[ESTADO]
        ,van.[ESTADO_COD]
        ,van.[PRODUTO]
        ,van.[VELOCIDADE_ACESSO]
        ,van.[CodCliente]
        ,van.[tipo_saida_atend]
        ,van.[CAR_COD_GRUPO]
        ,van.[CAR_GRUPO]
        ,van.[CAR_RAZAO_SOCIAL]
        ,van.[CAR_SEGMENTO_CATEGORIA]
        ,van.[CAR_SEGMENTO_VALOR]
        ,van.[CAR_SERVICE_MANAGER]
        ,van.[CAR_LIDER_POS_VENDAS]
        ,van.[CAR_COORDENADOR_POS_VENDAS]
        ,van.[CAR_GERENTE_POS_VENDAS]
        ,van.[TIPO_SMART]
        ,n.[NodeID]
        ,n.[IP_Address]
        ,n.[Country]
        ,n.[Nome_do_cliente]
        ,n.[Nome_do_device]
        ,n.[Nome_do_site]
        ,n.[Operação]
        ,n.[Operadora]
        ,n.[Pacote_Smart]
    FROM **[THE DATABASE NAME1]**. [VANTIVE].[dbo].[TABELACO] AS van
    INNER JOIN **[THE DATABASE NAME2]**. [SOLARWINDS].[dbo].[TB_NODES_SMART] AS n
    ON van.[ID_VANTIVE] = n.[NodeID]``
```

Make sure you have permission to access the database from one another